# PHPExcel Spreadsheet cell contains ### bydefault

Tags: phpexcel

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upNEB.png)

I've added a calculation in that cell (e:g D6 = (C6/B6)) and as I need that value in percentage, So I used the following:

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D6')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#.##');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D6')->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( array('code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00) );

On clicking a button, I'm downloading the excel sheet and by default I'm getting the '###' symbols.

On Expanding that cell I've my values.

I have also given setAutoSize(true).

Any help?